# Getting null in LayoutInflater inside getView()

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a `ListFragment`.
Each row in the list contains an image and text. Much like [this](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorials/images/Android_Custom_ListView_ArrayAdapter.png).
I am following the approach of implementing the view using `ArrayAdapter`.

But I'm getting **NullPointerException** @ `LayoutInflater inflater = fragmentContext.getLayoutInflater(null);` inside getView() of ArrayAdapter

Code :

ArrayAdapter Class:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] items;
    Fragment fragmentContext;

    public MyListAdapter(Context c, int textViewResourceId, String[] listItmes,
            Fragment fragmentContext) {
        super(c, textViewResourceId, listItmes);
            this.items = listItmes;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = fragmentContext.getLayoutInflater(null);
            view.inflate(context, R.layout.my_row, null);
        }
        if (items != null) {
            TextView tv_my_list_item_title = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_my_list_item_title);
            if (tv_my_list_item_title != null) {
                tv_my_list_item_title.setText(items[position]);
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

ListFragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;
    String[] listItems = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
        listItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_element_list);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Populate list with our static array of titles.
        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        //      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.my_row, listItems, this);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) { // Restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        showDetails(position);
    }

    private void showDetails(int position) {
        mCurCheckPosition = position;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), listItems[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

mylayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

my_row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_mehr_list_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_mehr_list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the below

```
LayoutInflater inflater ;
public MyListAdapter(Context c, int textViewResourceId, String[] listItmes,
            Fragment fragmentContext) {
            super(c, textViewResourceId, listItmes);
            this.items = listItmes;
            inflater = LayoutInfalter.from(c);
        }
```

And in `getView()` use

```
  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row,parent, false);
```

There is no need to initialize inflater in `getView`. You need to intialize the inflated view to `view` coz you have `View view = convertView` and then use the inlfated view object to initialize your textview.

Edit:

Also i would suggest you use a view holder pattern

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: Thanks, but the text in the `TextView` is not getting displayed. Any suggestions?

Comment: i suggest you use a view holder pattern and initialize your textview when view is null. check if you have initialized textview properly and check if you have data in your items array

Answer (score 2):

```
    Context context;
    String[] items;
    Fragment fragmentContext;

public MyListAdapter(Context c, int textViewResourceId, String[] listItmes,
            Fragment fragmentContext) {
        super(c, textViewResourceId, listItmes);
            this.items = listItmes;
        }
    }
```

you are not assigning the context passed to `fragmentContext` inside the constructor.. so it remains null

add inside the constructor

```
        this.fragmentContext = fragmentContext;
```